# So wierd that python convert my pathname from mac to win format

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import an api from a path, the spec_win works well on windows but when I change to my mac, it gives error msg:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a4fad978c432> in <module>
      2 spec_mac = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("lumapi", "/Applications/Lumerical v202.app/Contents/API/Python/lumapi.py")
      3 lumapi = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec_mac)
----> 4 spec.loader.exec_module(lumapi) ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in get_code(self, fullname)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in get_data(self, path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\Lumerical\\v202\\api\\python\\lumapi.py'
```

```py
spec_win = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("lumapi", "C:\\Program Files\\Lumerical\\v202\\api\\python\\lumapi.py")
spec_mac = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("lumapi", "/Applications/Lumerical v202.app/Contents/API/Python/lumapi.py")
lumapi = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec_mac)
spec.loader.exec_module(lumapi)
```

Comment: spec_mac.loader.exec_module(lumapi)

Comment: What is ``spec``?